# How to call json_encode function from php to asp.Net with C#?

Tags: c#, php, json

I am trying to call PHP file containing information in JSON format.

Here is my code from Request.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
session_start();

$conn =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","akshat", "staff");
                                if ($conn === false) {
                                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                                } 
$sqlgrp="select staff.groupid from staff.STAFF where staff.NAME='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$resultgrp = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlgrp);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultgrp) > 0) {
    while($rowgrp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultgrp)) {
    $grp=$rowgrp['groupid'];
                }
    }

$myObj->name = $_SESSION["username"];
$myObj->branchno = $_SESSION["branch"];
$myObj->group = $grp;

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my c# code :

```
public void GetResult(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            string jsonstring = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())


 {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                jsonstring = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string compiled = Regex.Match(jsonstring, "(?s)<body[^>]*>(.*)</body>").Groups[1].Value;
                jsonString.Text = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(compiled).ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

When I run php in browser it shows values

when making request from c# I get,

```
{ "name": null, "branchno": null, "group": "1" }
```

What could have gone possibly wrong?

How to get values in Json Format? All I get is null.

Comment: Either the php response differs (use logs to determine) or the c# code is not doing what you think/want. Please determine which it is and update the question accordingly. `$myObj->branchno = $_SESSION["branch"];` - where is this being set?

Comment: You're getting a `<body></body>` in a JSON response ?

Comment: @Cid yes. I am getting whole html page

Comment: @AD7six it is set when user is logged in. In request.php page these parameters are set.

Comment: @David put the code relevant to that in the question please, and indicate how your c# code is triggering it.

Comment: if you're getting a html page for a json request (and _especially_ if that's intentional) there's a whole lot more to worry about than what you're asking :) (and that's ignoring the php sql injection vulnerability in the code in the question).

Comment: @AD7six updated code in question!

Comment: There is nothing in the question to indicate `$_SESSION["branch"];` is set in the c# request you're asking about. Good luck :)

Comment: Just to mention it. Are you aware you are using a doctype that no one should be using since 1999? Even then, only as one transitions to the proper HTML 4.01 doctype which itself is now obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your shared json you are getting `null` in name and branhno but group is having value.

```
{ "name": null, "branchno": null, "group": "1" }
```

I think you need to check and validate rather this session variable is having value when your are setting it to the name and branch attribute.

```
$myObj->name = $_SESSION["username"];
$myObj->branchno = $_SESSION["branch"];
```

and if session has value then the issue is in json decode function.